# Explain the Hash in url like /#/

Tags: php, html, url, seo, web-deployment

Anyone can please explain this to me that why there is a Hash at the end of this url   https://www.coinsuper.com/#/ ?

For example, when I open this website as www.coinsuper.com its automatically shows /#/ at the end.

Also, when I open this website on a smartphone it shows a separate version.

Will it (#) affect doing SEO?

PS: Please in this question I am focusing on /#/ and it will help you to understand my question when you will visit the above-mentioned website on both desktop and mobile too. because it is not something like hash anchoring which leads us to a specific section of a web page.

Comment: One explanation of the hash at the end of URLS is the webpage could be made with [`HashRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter). This doesn't affect SEO, and is just used to keep track of the current state of the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

That is a fragment identifier. Among other things, you can use it to identify different parts on your page.

It could actually help with SEO if the name of the fragment being identified lines up with content that Google finds appropriate.